# Writing Unit test to Launch WPF popup window using Caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, nunit, caliburn.micro

I want to write a test for a WPF application(Caliburn micro & autofac). The purpose of this test is to display a popup window from unit test case. I tried writing with stand alone WPF window and it worked:

But when I tried to integrate it to an existing solution which uses Caliburn micro & autofac and contains dictionaries and styles I got into some problems:

```
    public MyViewModelTest()
    {
        this.repository = new MockRepository();
        var eventAggregator = this.repository.Stub<IEventAggregator>();
        //Other dependencies
        viewModel = new MyViewModel(eventAggregator, other dependencies);
        GenerateDummyData();



    }

    [Test]
    public void OpenMyViewModelTest()
    {

        var uiThread = new Thread(Show);
        uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        uiThread.Start();
        // Wait for the UI thread to finish
        uiThread.Join();

    }

    private void Show()
    {
        //TODO make a new window to test and uncomment it.
        var fg = new MyView { Height = 500, Width = 500, DataContext = viewModel };
        //var fg = new MainView { Height = 500, Width = 500, DataContext = viewModel };

        fg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Now if I execute the test from separate test project solution(Not with in UI project where view, viewmodels are available) I get an exception that:

SetUp : System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'ABC.UIAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

If I copy and run test from WPF UI project an empty window get lanuched.

So, I am wondering if I am missing some thing.
do I need to explicitly provide style resources, dictionaries and images etc to the WPF window with in the test.

A link on how write a test case for WPF window with caliburn micro would be a plus.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually testing?

Comment: I want to test a Popup window. Whether it displays the data correctly and its design and layout if I provide fake data using the test. One more reason is that this window gets open very rarely during the application flow. So, I want a test case so whenever someone make changes in this window. It can be tested.